# ElasticSearch basic query, why doesn't it work

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to learn how to query ElasticSearch. My background is in database development and I keep thinking about sql way of doing it. I did read ES docs about different types of query, but many of it still won't make sense to me. I have several question and really hope someone can shed some light to help me out.

1. Is there a difference between _search and _search?search_type=count?
2. Is there a way I can query mapping, so I can see field names and types?
3. I need to bring back app, cat and sub fields from all documents where app="AAA".

Why wouldn't something like this work?

```
{
  "fields":["app","cat","sub"],
  "query":{
        "field" : {
            "app.raw": "AAA"
        }
    },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I really think you should try to find the answer in the manual. To help out: search_type=count does not return hits. Look for _mapping and you probably want to have a look at the term query or even better term filter. And finally look for _source_include instead of fields.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there a difference between _search and _search?search_type=count?

Yes, the latter which will **not** return the actual hits. If you only need to know how many documents it would have matched or if you only need the result of the filters/aggregations, then the latter is for you.

> 2. Is there a way I can query mapping, so I can see field names and types?

Use the [get mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) endpoint: http://localhost:9200/index/type/_mapping?pretty

The syntax has various incarnations, I used `type/_mapping` but you also can call it as `_mapping/type`

> 3. I need to bring back app, cat and sub fields from all documents where app="AAA".

Without knowing your mapping it's hard to *guess* what really went wrong.

Since you're using `app.raw` I assume you went along with maybe [Core Types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/mapping-core-types.html), which is a `not_analyzed` field and thus you probably should use a query which works best with it which would be the [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-term-query.html):

```
{
  "query":{
    "term" : {
      "app.raw": "AAA"
    }
  }
}
```

If the above doesn't solve it, please provide the output of `yourindex/yourtype/_mapping?pretty`.

Mastering the query DSL is important to make anything useful. I recommend reading [Query DSL reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html), going through the ["Search in Deptht"-Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/search-in-depth.html) and I can also the recommend the pretty recent video [Query DSL not just for Wizards](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/elasticsearch-query-dsl), de-mystifying some of the weird parts.